# $\int_A e^{-(x^2+y^2+xy)}$ where $A = \{(x,y): x^2+y^2+xy \leq 1 \}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I am trying to solve the following problem
$$\int_A e^{-(x^2+y^2+xy)}$$
where $A = \{(x,y): x^2+y^2+xy \leq 1 \}$.

I know how to solve the problem when the domain is $\mathbb{R}^2$: you complete the square and transform it into the Gaussian integral. I have tried to use a change of variables to polar coordinates but I get:

$$ \int^{2 \pi}_0 \int^{(1+\tfrac{1}{2} \sin(2 \theta)^{-1}}_{-(1+\tfrac{1}{2} \sin \theta)^{-1}} e^{-r^2 (1+\tfrac{1}{2} \sin(2 \theta))} r dr d\theta $$ but the calculations are fairly messy. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Standard polar coordinates will not help you. Select a transformation $$\begin{cases}x = a r\cos(\theta+\pi/4) \\ y = b r \sin(\theta + \pi/4)\end{cases}$$ with $a,b$ that make the integral the most simplified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ \displaystyle x^2 + y^2 + xy = \left(x + \frac y2\right)^2 + \left(\frac {\sqrt3 y}{2}\right)^2$

Using substitution $ \displaystyle u = x + \frac y2, v = \frac {\sqrt3 y}{2}$

$ \displaystyle |J| = \frac 2 {\sqrt3}$

$x^2 + y^2 + xy \leq 1 \implies u^2 + v^2 \leq 1$,
which is a unit circle.

So using polar coordinates, the integral translates to

$ \displaystyle  \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 r ~ e^{-r^2} |J| ~ dr ~ d\theta$